# How to find the source of a "Exception encountered unloading application domain" with the Nunit runner?

Tags: c#, nunit, nunit-3.0

We have a big bunch of tests(6000+) in differents assemblies. We run them on a local Azure Agent, with the Nunit Test adapter.

It was taking a very long time, so we activated the runInParallel.

The yaml step is now the following:

```yaml
  - task: VSTest@2
    timeoutInMinutes: 300
    inputs:
      testSelector: 'testAssemblies'
      testAssemblyVer2: '*.Test*.dll'
      searchFolder: '$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)/$(buildConfiguration)'
      codeCoverageEnabled: false
      platform: 'Any CPU'
      uiTests: false
      configuration: '$(buildConfiguration)'
      rerunFailedTests: false
      pathtoCustomTestAdapters: 'Solution/packages/NUnit3TestAdapter.3.12.0/build/net35'
      minimumExpectedTests: 1000
      runInParallel: true
      distributionBatchType: basedOnAssembly
      failOnMinTestsNotRun: true
      resultsFolder: 'testResults'
      runSettingsFile: '$(Build.SourcesDirectory)\azure-tests.runsettings'
    #continueOnError: true
```

Now, we get some tests that doesn't pass. I've analyzed one of them, and basically, it fails because at some point, it does a `OfType<SomeInterface>`. The objects in the collection does implement this interface, so I guess I must have an issue with this assembly loaded 2 time and this interface not being considered the same as the created objects.

When I check the logs, I now see this, which seems to confirm this theory:

```
##[warning]RunMessage : Exception NUnit.Engine.NUnitEngineUnloadException,    Exception thrown unloading tests from C:\DevOp\2\s\debug\Acceptance.Tests.dll
##[warning]RunMessage : Exception encountered unloading application domain
##[warning]RunMessage :    at NUnit.Engine.Services.DomainManager.DomainUnloader.Unload()
   at NUnit.Engine.Runners.TestDomainRunner.UnloadPackage()
   at NUnit.Engine.Runners.AbstractTestRunner.Dispose(Boolean disposing)
   at NUnit.Engine.Runners.AbstractTestRunner.Dispose()
   at NUnit.Engine.Runners.MasterTestRunner.Dispose(Boolean disposing)
   at NUnit.Engine.Runners.MasterTestRunner.Dispose()
   at NUnit.VisualStudio.TestAdapter.NUnit3TestExecutor.RunAssembly(String assemblyPath, TestFilter filter) in D:\repos\nunit\nunit3-vs-adapter\src\NUnitTestAdapter\NUnit3TestExecutor.cs:line 321
##[warning]RunMessage : Innerexception: NUnit.Engine.NUnitEngineException: Exception encountered unloading application domain: Error while unloading appdomain. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131015)
Application domain name: domain-dcec2bc8-Acceptance.Tests.dll
Application domain BaseDirectory: C:\DevOp\2\s\debug\
```

I've searched, but I didn't found how to solve this issue. I can understand, that I probably have something that prevent the assembly to properly unload, but we have more than 6000 tests, 15 tests assemblies which references some production code and some test code. The execution of all tests takes ~2h45.

How do I know what cannot be unloaded(and why?) How would you proceed to solve this error?

Comment: You may run it's locally and try to reproduce it and check an event log then

Comment: For testing this case create a new pipeline or modify this one and limit test to assembly where this failing test is. You can do this changing `testAssemblyVer2`. It should probably be just `Acceptance.Tests.dll`. And also please make sure it references all needed assemblies, also this which are not referenced directly via reflection.

Comment: @KrzysztofMadej We are currently only parallelizing per assembly, so running assembly per assembly will not show the bug ?

Comment: @PavelAnikhouski How to have more information than on Azure then?

Comment: @J4N if you are asking me I would tell - I don't know. Please try and check.

Comment: Well just did and all tests pass :/

Comment: @J4N Please login your build agent machine, navigate to the agent working folder, and run VSTest locally to see how's the result.

Comment: @CeceDong-MSFT Okay, but what make you think I will get more logs? When you say run VSTest, could this be done within VisualStudio?

Comment: @CeceDong-MSFT Yeah, so I did run this commandline: `vstest.console.exe Debug\Acceptance.Tests.dll --Parallel --TestAdapterPath:Solution/packages/NUnit3TestAdapter.3.12.0/build/net35 --Platform:x64`. Bug I get exactly the same UnloadException at the end, without having more information to know what is preventing this dll to unload.

Comment: @J4N Since you can reproduce this issue locally, this issue is related to your tests, not DevOps. You need to solve the issue locally first. You may run command with `--trace=Debug` to see whether you can get more log.

Comment: @CeceDong-MSFT it appears that I solved the issue locally by using elevated priviledge locally. How would you do this with an agent?

Comment: @J4N You could configure the build agent using the account that have elevated priviledge.

Comment: @CeceDong-MSFT The user that is in the "LogOn" of the service is in the "Administrators" group. Locally, to hav ethis working I had to use the "Compatibility troubleshot compatibility" on the vstest.console.exe to have it working. I tried to do the same on the vstest.console.exe used by the agent without any luck.

Comment: Can you share the detailed command you ran locally?

Comment: @CeceDong-MSFT Sure. `vstest.console.exe Debug\*.Test*.dll --Parallel --TestAdapterPath:Solution/packages/NUnit3TestAdapter.3.12.0/build/net35 --Platform:x64`

Comment: I actually want to know how you usde the "Compatibility troubleshot compatibility" on the vstest.console.exe..

Comment: No command: right-click, troubleshotcompatibility, application has insufficient right, ...

Comment: Did you find a solution to this problem? I'm seeing the same error on VSTS as well.